# how to calculate the radius of a trajectory with given 'x' and 'y' positions in R

Tags: r, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I have trajectories of some moving objects in a data frame for example three trajectories were considered here as shown below:

```
> d1 <- data.frame(X1 = c(86.46, 79.88, 73.63, 67.63, 61.78, 56.05, 50.40, 44.80, 39.25, 33.79, 28.49, 23.40, 18.53, 13.84, 9.31, 5.04, 1.12), 
             Y1 = c(4.28, 5.49, 6.80, 8.16, 9.59, 11.18, 13.05, 15.28, 17.86, 20.81, 24.12, 27.75, 31.68, 35.87, 40.31, 44.92, 49.61))

> d2 <- data.frame(X2 = c(0.32, 4.00,  8.00, 12.31, 16.87, 21.64, 26.60, 31.75, 37.08, 42.62, 48.36, 54.33, 60.59, 67.25, 74.48, 82.42), 
             Y2 = c(57.55, 52.67, 47.98, 43.49, 39.24, 35.26, 31.59, 28.24, 25.19, 22.42, 19.92, 17.65, 15.55, 13.54, 11.54, 9.47))

> d3 <- data.frame(X3 = c(0.04, 1.76,  3.61, 5.63, 7.89, 10.42, 13.19, 16.14, 19.25, 22.61, 26.29, 30.35, 34.83, 39.71, 44.97, 50.58, 56.47, 62.56, 68.79, 75.19, 81.82),
             Y3 = c(58.34, 55.97, 53.49, 50.89, 48.15, 45.27, 42.35, 39.43, 36.50, 33.57, 30.66, 27.85, 25.18, 22.66, 20.27, 18.02, 15.94, 14.02, 12.22, 10.48, 8.83))


my.lists <- list(d1, d2, d3)

df12 <- do.call(qpcR:::cbind.na, my.lists)
```

now I would like to calculate the radius of each trajectory in the df12 data frame. 
from each trajectory we can get useful parameters such as arc length and chord length as follows:

```
#for arc length
> library(geosphere) ## for calculating distance between successive points #step-1:

> d11 <-  data.frame(Distance = sqrt(diff(d1$X1)^2 + diff(d1$Y1)^2)) #step-2: 

> d11$csum1 <- ave(d11$Distance, FUN=cumsum) #step-3: 

#for chord length
> sqrt((d1[1,1]-d1[17,1])^2+(d1[1,2]-d1[17,2])^2)
```

is there any approach to calculate the radius of a trajectory?

thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if a package already exists, but you can calculate the radius of a circle from three points, see http://www.ambrsoft.com/TrigoCalc/Circle3D.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not completely clear what you mean with "radius of a trajectory".
Here I assume you want to *fit* data points of a trajectory with a circle
that runs through these points. We will look at your first example.

```
library(pracma)
x <- d1$X1; y <- d1$Y1              # data points
res <- circlefit(x, y, fast=TRUE)   # "fitting a circle"
res
## RMS error: 0.2696326 
## [1]  93.85894 123.25466 118.51384
```

This computes a circle of radius `r0 = 118.51384` and the center at
`(93.85894, 123.25466)` with an RMS error of about `0.27`. To visualize:

```
x0 <- res[1]; y0 <- res[2]; r0 <- res[3]    # center and radius
ts <- seq(0, 2*pi, length.out = 100)
xs <- x0 + r0*cos(ts); ys <- y0 + r0*sin(ts)

plot(xs, ys, type='l', col = "red", asp=1)
points(x, y); grid()
```

Do not use the `fast = FALSE` option in `circlefit`, the optimization
process steered by `optim()` runs wild.

You can also apply function `CircleFitBy...()` in package *conicfit* --
maybe that's even the better alternative. It depends also on what your
preferred 'measure of fit' is.

Comment: @ Hand W. does the 'circlefit' fit the circle and calculates the radius by minimizing the RMS error? I would like to calculate the radius adopted by an object from its trajectory.

Comment: Please read the documentation. It is not possible to determine the radius from three points of the trajectory, *except* all points lie *exactly* on a circle. For your example this is not the case: Taking every set of three points on the trajectory, the values of the different radii lie in the range of `[99, 385]` with a mean of 128, so certainly not on a perfect circle.

Comment: Yes you are right. so in the above answer, the circle is being fitted for the data we have which has the minimum RMS error!